# Remove Value In MySQL Field

Tags: mysql

I have thousands of fields and each has a youtube video at the bottom. I need to remove just the YouTube video emebedded code from each field. Here's the SQL command I'm running but it does nothing.

```
UPDATE MYTABLE SET my_field = REPLACE(page_content, '<div align="center"><iframe src="https://www.youtube.com/embed/xxxxxxxxxx" width="560" height="315" frameborder="0" allowfullscreen="allowfullscreen"></iframe></div> ', '');
```

Am I missing something here? Thanks in advance!

Comment: Please provide sample data and desired results. Your code updates `my_field` from another column, called `page_content`, so it is not really *replacing* values.

Comment: Thanks for the reply. The sample data is in the command above. It starts at the div tag and ends with the closing div tag. The desired result is to remove that embedded youtube code.


<div align="center"><iframe src="https://www.youtube.com/embed/xxxxxxxxxx" width="560" height="315" frameborder="0" allowfullscreen="allowfullscreen"></iframe></div>

Comment: Can anyone assist with this?